# list of arrays into array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist

I have a problem that I can't solve. Here is the thing. As a result of iteration, for each item I get one array with one object inside. I would like it to be one array that has all object items inside in order for further mapping and filtering. Later I'll need it to be json.

```
        console.log(data)
```

```
 [...][...] ... [...] // result
```

```
I want:
```

```
{ [...], [...] ... [...] } // this I want
```

```
I tried push, join, merge and spread operator without any luck.
```

code:

```
      const body = [];

      const result = await fetch(uls, options);

      body.push({
        textBody: await result.text(),
        url: i.contentUrl,
      });

      const allAddedHashtags = body
        .map((i) => {
          const searchFor = /([+]hashtags: [^\n]*(\n+))/g;
          return {
            hashtags: i.textBody.match(searchFor),
            url: i.url,
          };
        })
        .filter((i) => i.hashtags !== null && i.hashtags.length === 2)
        .map((i) => {
          return {
            original: i.hashtags[0]
              .replace(/[+]hashtags: "/g, "")
              .replace(/"\n/g, "")
              .split(",")
              .sort(),
            edited: i.hashtags[1]
              .replace(/[+]hashtags: "/g, "")
              .replace(/"\n/g, "")
              .replace(/\n/g, "")
              .replace(/##/g, "#")
              .replace(/ #/g, "#")
              .replace(/"#/g, "#")
              .replace(/\"/g, "")
              .split(",")
              .sort(),
            url: i.url,
          };
        })
        .map((i) => {
          return {
            keep: i.edited.filter((x) => !new Set(i.original).has(x)),
            url: i.url,
          };
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)?

Comment: yes I have. And flat and concat

Comment: can you provide `console.log(data)` and maybe the result you want as well?

Comment: full array/json before iteration ok too

Comment: {
  keep: ['a'],
  url: 'https://a.com/1'
}
{
  keep: ['b', 'c'],
  url: 'https://a.com/2'
}
{
  keep: ['a', 'd'],
  url: 'https://a.com/3'
}

Comment: Edit in your question please, is that an array or json? `[ { keep: ['a'], url: 'a.com/1' }, { keep: ['b', 'c'], url: 'a.com/2' }, { keep: ['a', 'd'], url: 'a.com/3' } ]` or `{ { keep: ['a'], url: 'a.com/1' }, { keep: ['b', 'c'], url: 'a.com/2' }, { keep: ['a', 'd'], url: 'a.com/3' } }`